# Robolectric Custom ShadowContextWrapper

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

**Problem**

I want to create a custom ShadowContextWrapper and implement getExternalFilesDirs() so it's compatible with AppCompat KitKat.

However when I do so I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempted to invoke public java.io.File robolectric.ShadowContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String) on instance of class org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication, but ShadowApplication doesn't extend ShadowContextWrapper

For those who are curious, here's the error output when SDK is 21 not 18 in robolectric test:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2388)
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextImpl.java:1046)
>   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextWrapper.java:216)   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatKitKat.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextCompatKitKat.java:29) 
>   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextCompat.java:220)

**Code**

```
/**
* Shadow for {@link android.content.ContextWrapper}.
*/
@Implements(ContextWrapper.class)
public class ShadowContextWrapper extends org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContextWrapper {
    public static final String TAG = ShadowContextWrapper.class.getSimpleName();

    @Implementation
    public File getExternalFilesDirs(String type) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Custom Shadow: " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
        return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type);
    }
```

}

Comment: I think you will get quicker answer on the robolectric github page

Comment: Good suggestion. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1984